# Need to know about using setInitial method in Java programming

Tags: java, android, arrays

I need to write a method using  `setInitial(int[] x)`  that can set the first 3 indices of a given array to 10, 100, and 342 respectively, and return the array. And this need to be done for java in Android Studio.

I am really struggling with understanding how to do this for assignment and I need an answer to this question in less than 24 hours.  so far I have done the following that can add integers 10, 100, 342 to the first 3 indices in x. (x is the name of my array).

```
x [0] = 10;

x [1] = 100;

x [2] = 342;
```

I am really not understanding this very well.

Comment: Delete the space between `x` and `[`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Your best bet for getting answers here is to try something and post your code.  Say what you expected and what you got and someone can help you a lot easier.  Check here for help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in it's most basic form:

```
public void setInitial(int[] x)
{
    x [0] = 10;
    x [1] = 100;
    x [2] = 342;
}
```

notice there is no bounds checking in this simple example

Answer (score 0):

Well first you need to understand how arrays work. There is something called an index and an element in an array. 
For example lets say you have 5 friends named Friend A, Friend B, Friend C, Friend D, Friend E.
You want to know what color your friend's clothes are so what do you do? You would call Friend A and ask what he or she is wearing. You wouldn't ask Friend B to ask about Friend A's clothes.
The same is with Arrays X[0] <-- is the index like your friend example A,B,C,D and the elements are like the color of his/her she. Each index or "friend" may have the same or different clothes, in terms of java "value".

I am unsure how your method is written or given but I would assume it goes something like

```
public void setInitial(int [] x) {

 int x[0] = 1; // Now index 0 has the element of 1
 ... so on and so on 
}
```

Comment: Thats makes so much much more sense than how its been explained in class. Thanks SO much.